# I have used advanced_in_app_review plugin, but rating dialog not popup

Tags: android, ios, flutter, rating, review

I have used advanced_in_app_review plugin, but rating dialog not popup

```
 void initState()  {
     super.initState();
 
     //initPlatformState(),
 
     AdvancedInAppReview()
         .setMinDaysBeforeRemind(7)
         .setMinDaysAfterInstall(2)
         .setMinLaunchTimes(2)
         .monitor();
     }
```

I removed initPlatformState() because it is useless.
now it seems that rating dialog not showing automatically, Should I add initPlatformState()?
or is it the issue of this plugin?
https://github.com/eeoom/advanced_in_app_review/issues/2

Answer (score 1):

Using the cascade operator when calling multiple methods on one object is safer:

```
AdvancedInAppReview()
         ..setMinDaysBeforeRemind(7)
         ..setMinDaysAfterInstall(2)
         ..setMinLaunchTimes(2)
         ..monitor();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, could you tell me can I remove initPlatformState()?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to remove initPlatformState().
It's not an issue of plugin.
In app reviews do not show up every time. The operating system decides when the alert is shown. The parameters of the plug in indicate only the minimum values before the system is asked to show the dialog, but as I said, the system decides afterwards if the dialog is shown.

Please note also that it is not shown in debug mode of android.